# Intellij underlining view and showing 'cannot resolve MVC view' but it can be accesed via browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

This is a very weird problem in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate that really bugs me out.
I have created a Controller that returns a view.

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting.html";
    }
```

The IDE (Intellij) underlines the greeting.html and shows 'cannot resolve MVC view greeting.html'. But when I open it in browser it shows just fine?
This is not really a big deal but it really irks me out since I have heavy OCD.
A fix would be much appreciated.

Comment: Am I got you right that when you deployed your application mappings worked fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed the return value to just "greeting" it stopped being underlined!
But it seems it is not a problem for spring to find the view either way.